# JavaFX XYChart Logarithmic plot

Tags: javafx-2

I have a XYChart plotting data as linear steps on Y axis, I would like to plot as logarithmic or semi-logarithmic Y scale, how to change my following code?

```
public class BaseXYChart extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
   stage.setTitle("Linear plot");

   final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
   final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 22, 0.5);

   yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis){
        @Override
    public String toString(Number object){
        return String.format("%7.2f", object);
    }
});
final LineChart<String, Number>lineChart = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

   lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
   lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);

   XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 1.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 2.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 3));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 6));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 9));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 12));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 15));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 20));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 22));

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(lineChart);          
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);

    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not possible in JavaFX Vanilla. But you can take a look here : http://blog.dooapp.com/2013/06/logarithmic-scale-strikes-back-in.html

Comment: Thanks, I've found this example (the only one available on the net!) some days ago, but you deserve your reply as my accepted answer for your advise

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: Quick search on the blog allowed me to find again the article